# PHP shell_exec cannot find environment variable

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have added this line `PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:~/bin/` to the `~/.pam_environment`
This allows me to call `ffmpeg` from command line without path which is obviously in `~/bin/` dir so everything works fine as long as im ussing command line.

But if try to run the exact same command from php all i get is `sh: ffmpeg: not found`
And the code is

`shell_exec("ffmpeg 2>&1");`

So from my very little experiance with linux (in this case Ubuntu to be specific) i guess apache has no access to `pam_environment` or `~/bin`

What can i do to make this work?

Comment: use shell_exec("/bin/ffmpeg 2>&1"); ?

Comment: iirc the ~ is your home dir. So that would be a different directory for apache, wouldn't it? Try setting the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the output of `phpinfo()`, it has a section with all environment variables it sees.  then look at your webserver configuration, maybe it's sanitizing the environment, or maybe the init script which starts your webserver does it.

and is the account the webserver is running under using PAM at all?

Comment: Okay so environment doesnt have path that i set in `~/.pam_environment` where can i find whats removing it?

Comment: Well i got it, now it says permission denied thou, but thats no longer related to this question, thanks for helping.